# Can only one person in a group of 2-4 people have a Wunderwaffe or Thundergun on Zombies?

Tags: call-of-duty-series

I've seen videos that have tricks on how to get 4 Wunderwaffes or 4 Thunderguns, does that mean it's not possible for multiple players to have the same wonder weapon during the same match?

Sorry if this should be common knowledge, I *have* played lots of Zombies across different Call of Duty games but never focus too much on story line/rules (just the basics).

The videos I'm talking about:

[Thundergun](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uPX-RKaO55E)

[Wunderwaffe](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O9iVmyE-XdE)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No, you cannot**.

However, according to [this website](https://community.guitarhero.com/t5/Call-of-Duty-Black-Ops-forum/Possible-for-2-players-to-have-wonder-weapons/td-p/4268711), your group may obtain multiple RayGuns!

Other wise, only one Wonder Weapon at a time.